# Indefinite integral from derivation of KL divergence for univariate gaussians

Tags: real-analysis, probability, statistics, probability-distributions

In this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/kl-divergence-between-two-univariate-gaussians) they claim the following

> Let $p(x)=N\left(\mu_{1}, \sigma_{1}\right)$ and $q(x)=N\left(\mu_{2}, \sigma_{2}\right) .$ From Bishop's PRML I know that $$ K L(p, q)=-\int
>  p(x) \log q(x) d x+\int p(x) \log p(x) d x $$ where integration is
>   done over all real line, and that $$ \int p(x) \log p(x) d x=-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\log 2 \pi \sigma_{1}^{2}\right) $$

However I do not understand how they arrive at the result of the last indefinite integral. As far as I can see it assumes that the integral of the gaussian distribution $p(x)$ is 1, which I cannot get right. As far as i can see when I look at other sources the integral of a gaussian is 
a lot more complex. How are they arriving at this?

EDIT: [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions) to source of gaussian integrals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$p(x)$ is a normal probability density function so the area under it is $1$.

(It would be helpful if you could expand on your other sources with more complex results.)

Comment: Ah yes. I think i have confused myself. I was looking at the link in the edit. @PM.